# Pygame Tetris won't close properly on main game screen

Tags: python, pygame

I recently followed a Youtube tutorial for a Tetris game, The error only seems to happen on the main game screen when you try to exit the program entirely, if you exit on the start screen it closes perfectly fine. If I close out on the main game screen, the following errors populate:

```
 File "C:\Users\OneDrive\import pygame", line 400, in <module>
    main_menu(win)
  File "C:\Users\OneDrive\import pygame", line 393, in main_menu
    main(win)
  File "C:\Users\OneDrive\import pygame", line 371, in main
    draw_window(win, grid, score, last_score)
  File "C:\Users\OneDrive\import pygame", line 265, in draw_window
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))
pygame.error: display Surface quit
```

Here is a breakdown of each block of code:

Line 265:

```
def draw_window(surface, grid, score=0, last_score = 0):
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))

    pygame.font.init()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
    label = font.render('Tetris', 1, (255, 255, 255))
```

Line 371

```
 draw_window(win, grid, score, last_score)
        draw_next_shape(next_piece, win)
        pygame.display.update()
```

Line 383-395

```
def main_menu(win):  
    run = True
    while run:
        win.fill((0,0,0))
        draw_text_middle(win, 'Press Any Key To Play', 60, (255,255,255))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                main(win)

    pygame.display.quit()
```

Line 398 - 400

```
  win = pygame.display.set_mode((s_width, s_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Tetris')
    main_menu(win)
```

I compared mine word for word against the source code, and it seems the source code also has this issue from what I can see. I am brand new to coding and would appreciate any help given! I have the full thing pasted below. I just want it to be able to close out perfectly whenever the user chooses to do so. Here is the link to the Source code I followed (https://www.techwithtim.net/tutorials/game-development-with-python/tetris-pygame/tutorial-4/)

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.font.init()

s_width = 800
s_height = 700
play_width = 300  # meaning 300 // 10 = 30 width per block
play_height = 600  # meaning 600 // 20 = 30 height per block
block_size = 30

top_left_x = (s_width - play_width) // 2
top_left_y = s_height - play_height


# SHAPE FORMATS

S = [['.....',
      '.....',
      '..00.',
      '.00..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '..00.',
      '...0.',
      '.....']]

Z = [['.....',
      '.....',
      '.00..',
      '..00.',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '.00..',
      '.0...',
      '.....']]

I = [['..0..',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '0000.',
      '.....',
      '.....',
      '.....']]

O = [['.....',
      '.....',
      '.00..',
      '.00..',
      '.....']]

J = [['.....',
      '.0...',
      '.000.',
      '.....',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..00.',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '.....',
      '.000.',
      '...0.',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '.00..',
      '.....']]

L = [['.....',
      '...0.',
      '.000.',
      '.....',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '..00.',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '.....',
      '.000.',
      '.0...',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '.00..',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '.....']]

T = [['.....',
      '..0..',
      '.000.',
      '.....',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '..00.',
      '..0..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '.....',
      '.000.',
      '..0..',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '.00..',
      '..0..',
      '.....']]

shapes = [S, Z, I, O, J, L, T]
shape_colors = [(0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 255), (255, 255, 0), (255, 165, 0), (0, 0, 255), (128, 0, 128)]
# index 0 - 6 represent shape


class Piece(object):  # *
    def __init__(self, x, y, shape):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.shape = shape
        self.color = shape_colors[shapes.index(shape)]
        self.rotation = 0


def create_grid(locked_pos={}):  # *
    grid = [[(0,0,0) for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(20)]

    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            if (j, i) in locked_pos:
                c = locked_pos[(j,i)]
                grid[i][j] = c
    return grid


def convert_shape_format(shape):
    positions = []
    format = shape.shape[shape.rotation % len(shape.shape)]

    for i, line in enumerate(format):
        row = list(line)
        for j, column in enumerate(row):
            if column == '0':
                positions.append((shape.x + j, shape.y + i))

    for i, pos in enumerate(positions):
        positions[i] = (pos[0] - 2, pos[1] - 4)

    return positions


def valid_space(shape, grid):
    accepted_pos = [[(j, i) for j in range(10) if grid[i][j] == (0,0,0)] for i in range(20)]
    accepted_pos = [j for sub in accepted_pos for j in sub]

    formatted = convert_shape_format(shape)

    for pos in formatted:
        if pos not in accepted_pos:
            if pos[1] > -1:
                return False
    return True


def check_lost(positions):
    for pos in positions:
        x, y = pos
        if y < 1:
            return True

    return False


def get_shape():
    return Piece(5, 0, random.choice(shapes))


def draw_text_middle(surface, text, size, color):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", size, bold=True)
    label = font.render(text, 1, color)

    surface.blit(label, (top_left_x + play_width /2 - (label.get_width()/2), top_left_y + play_height/2 - label.get_height()/2))


def draw_grid(surface, grid):
    sx = top_left_x
    sy = top_left_y

    for i in range(len(grid)):
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (128,128,128), (sx, sy + i*block_size), (sx+play_width, sy+ i*block_size))
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            pygame.draw.line(surface, (128, 128, 128), (sx + j*block_size, sy),(sx + j*block_size, sy + play_height))


def clear_rows(grid, locked):

    inc = 0
    for i in range(len(grid)-1, -1, -1):
        row = grid[i]
        if (0,0,0) not in row:
            inc += 1
            ind = i
            for j in range(len(row)):
                try:
                    del locked[(j,i)]
                except:
                    continue

    if inc > 0:
        for key in sorted(list(locked), key=lambda x: x[1])[::-1]:
            x, y = key
            if y < ind:
                newKey = (x, y + inc)
                locked[newKey] = locked.pop(key)

    return inc


def draw_next_shape(shape, surface):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 30)
    label = font.render('Next Shape', 1, (255,255,255))

    sx = top_left_x + play_width + 50
    sy = top_left_y + play_height/2 - 100
    format = shape.shape[shape.rotation % len(shape.shape)]

    for i, line in enumerate(format):
        row = list(line)
        for j, column in enumerate(row):
            if column == '0':
                pygame.draw.rect(surface, shape.color, (sx + j*block_size, sy + i*block_size, block_size, block_size), 0)

    surface.blit(label, (sx + 10, sy - 30))


def update_score(nscore):
    score = max_score()

    with open('scores.txt', 'w') as f:
        if int(score) > nscore:
            f.write(str(score))
        else:
            f.write(str(nscore))


def max_score():
    with open('scores.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        score = lines[0].strip()

    return score


def draw_window(surface, grid, score=0, last_score = 0):
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))

    pygame.font.init()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
    label = font.render('Tetris', 1, (255, 255, 255))

    surface.blit(label, (top_left_x + play_width / 2 - (label.get_width() / 2), 30))

    # current score
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 30)
    label = font.render('Score: ' + str(score), 1, (255,255,255))

    sx = top_left_x + play_width + 50
    sy = top_left_y + play_height/2 - 100

    surface.blit(label, (sx + 20, sy + 160))
    # last score
    label = font.render('High Score: ' + last_score, 1, (255,255,255))

    sx = top_left_x - 200
    sy = top_left_y + 200

    surface.blit(label, (sx + 20, sy + 160))

    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, grid[i][j], (top_left_x + j*block_size, top_left_y + i*block_size, block_size, block_size), 0)

    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255, 0, 0), (top_left_x, top_left_y, play_width, play_height), 5)

    draw_grid(surface, grid)
    #pygame.display.update()


def main(win):  # *
    last_score = max_score()
    locked_positions = {}
    grid = create_grid(locked_positions)

    change_piece = False
    run = True
    current_piece = get_shape()
    next_piece = get_shape()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    fall_time = 0
    fall_speed = 0.27
    level_time = 0
    score = 0

    while run:
        grid = create_grid(locked_positions)
        fall_time += clock.get_rawtime()
        level_time += clock.get_rawtime()
        clock.tick()

        if level_time/1000 > 5:
            level_time = 0
            if level_time > 0.12:
                level_time -= 0.005

        if fall_time/1000 > fall_speed:
            fall_time = 0
            current_piece.y += 1
            if not(valid_space(current_piece, grid)) and current_piece.y > 0:
                current_piece.y -= 1
                change_piece = True

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.display.quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    current_piece.x -= 1
                    if not(valid_space(current_piece, grid)):
                        current_piece.x += 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    current_piece.x += 1
                    if not(valid_space(current_piece, grid)):
                        current_piece.x -= 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    current_piece.y += 1
                    if not(valid_space(current_piece, grid)):
                        current_piece.y -= 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    current_piece.rotation += 1
                    if not(valid_space(current_piece, grid)):
                        current_piece.rotation -= 1

        shape_pos = convert_shape_format(current_piece)

        for i in range(len(shape_pos)):
            x, y = shape_pos[i]
            if y > -1:
                grid[y][x] = current_piece.color

        if change_piece:
            for pos in shape_pos:
                p = (pos[0], pos[1])
                locked_positions[p] = current_piece.color
            current_piece = next_piece
            next_piece = get_shape()
            change_piece = False
            score += clear_rows(grid, locked_positions) * 10

        draw_window(win, grid, score, last_score)
        draw_next_shape(next_piece, win)
        pygame.display.update()

        if check_lost(locked_positions):
            draw_text_middle(win, "YOU LOST!", 80, (255,255,255))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1500)
            run = False
            update_score(score)


def main_menu(win):  # *
    run = True
    while run:
        win.fill((0,0,0))
        draw_text_middle(win, 'Press Any Key To Play', 60, (255,255,255))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                main(win)

    pygame.display.quit()


win = pygame.display.set_mode((s_width, s_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tetris')
main_menu(win)
```

There is also another file which updates the High score:

```
def update_score(nscore):
    score = max_score()

    with open('scores.txt', 'w') as f:
        if int(score) > nscore:
            f.write(str(score))
        else:
            f.write(str(nscore))
def max_score():
    with open('scores.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        score = lines[0].strip()

    return score
```

Comment: you may have to use `sys.exit()`  to exit program at once, or `return` to exit function at once. If you don't do this then it will run next lines in function and they may still run code which need access to screen. OR you shoudl only set `run = False` and line `pygame.display.quit()` run after loop `while run` - because `pygame.display.quit()` only close window but it doesn't finish program

Comment: `main_menu()` runs `main()` and when you close window then it does't exit program at once but it ends loop `while run` inside `main()` and it goes back to `main_menu()` which still runs `while`-loop - and this loop also need `run = False` to exit own loop before it will try to run `win.fill()`.

Answer (score 1):

`main_menu()` runs `main()` and when you close window then it doesn't stop program but it only close window and it goes back to `main_menu()` which runs own loop and it tries to access window (to display menu)

One solution is to use `sys.exit()` (or `exit()`) in `main()` to stop program at once.

```
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                #run = False
                pygame.display.quit()
                sys.exit()   # <-- exit program at once
```

---

Other solution is to use `run = False` in `main_menu()` after `main()` to stop this loop too.

```
def main_menu(win):  # *
    run = True
    while run:
        win.fill((0,0,0))
        draw_text_middle(win, 'Press Any Key To Play', 60, (255,255,255))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                main(win)
                run = False

    pygame.display.quit()
```

but this method needs modification to keep running when you `loose` in game.

It may need to use `return True` , `return False` in `main()`

```
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return False

        # ... code ...

        if check_lost(locked_positions):
           # ... code ...
           return True
```

and it `main_menu()` use this `True/False` to close loop

```
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                run = main(win)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I was stuck on this for 3 days total and this worked!!